# Segfault trying to access Users in Settings

Tags: debian, kali-linux, users, segmentation-fault

I am having a problematic issue that I can't seem to figure out. I am able to open the settings as root user just fine. When I click on Users, nothing happens. I am running on Linux kali 4.7.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.7.6-1kali1 (2016-10-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux. This is what I get in /var/log/syslog

`Oct 27 21:00:09 kali kernel: [  695.533180] gnome-control-c[1944]: segfault at 0 ip 00000000004c9a5d sp 00007fffae418480 error 4 in gnome-control-center[400000+394000]`

I have tried running the command: 
`addr2line -e /usr/bin/gnome-control-center -fCi 0xC9A5D` where 0xC9A5d is the offset into the object that was causing the problem and I get nothing.

I then ran:
`addr2line -e /usr/bin/gnome-control-center -fCi 0x00000000004c9a5d` and I get:

`cc_universal_access_get_resource
??:?`

Interesting...

I understand that the cause of this was that a user mode instruction resulted in a page fault. I have a couple gnome-control-center files of interest listed here:

/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/gnome-control-center

/usr/bin/gnome-control-center

I would doubt the problem was in the first file listed as it shell script for tab completion. So I try to run gdb on the binary, but it wasn't compiled with debugging it seems, since there aren't any debugging symbols to be found. The whole point of this was trying to create a new user so I can install steam on Kali to play some games in my spare time aside from messing with this darn system lol.

When I look at [Github](https://github.com/endlessm/gnome-control-center/tree/master/panels/universal-access) for gnome-control-center. I find the cc_ua_panel.c file. It has a method in it where I have found the call to cc_universal_access_get_resource as follows.

```
static void
cc_ua_panel_init (CcUaPanel *self)
{
  CcUaPanelPrivate *priv;
  GtkWidget *panel;
  GtkWidget *content;

  priv = self->priv = G_TYPE_INSTANCE_GET_PRIVATE (self,
                                                   CC_TYPE_UA_PANEL,
                                                   CcUaPanelPrivate);

  g_resources_register (cc_universal_access_get_resource ());

  priv->interface_settings = g_settings_new (INTERFACE_SETTINGS);
  priv->a11y_settings = g_settings_new (A11Y_SETTINGS);
  priv->wm_settings = g_settings_new (WM_SETTINGS);
  priv->kb_settings = g_settings_new (KEYBOARD_SETTINGS);
  priv->kb_desktop_settings = g_settings_new (KEYBOARD_DESKTOP_SETTINGS);
  priv->mouse_settings = g_settings_new (MOUSE_SETTINGS);
  priv->gsd_mouse_settings = g_settings_new (GSD_MOUSE_SETTINGS);
  priv->application_settings = g_settings_new (APPLICATION_SETTINGS);

  priv->builder = gtk_builder_new ();
  gtk_builder_add_from_resource (priv->builder,

                                 "/org/gnome/control-center/universal-access/uap.ui",
                                 NULL);

  cc_ua_panel_init_status (self);
  cc_ua_panel_init_seeing (self);
  cc_ua_panel_init_hearing (self);
  cc_ua_panel_init_keyboard (self);
  cc_ua_panel_init_mouse (self);

  panel = WID ("universal_access_panel");
  content = WID ("universal_access_content");

  gtk_scrolled_window_set_min_content_height (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (panel), SCROLL_HEIGHT);

  priv->focus_adjustment = gtk_scrolled_window_get_vadjustment (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (panel));
  gtk_container_set_focus_vadjustment (GTK_CONTAINER (content), priv->focus_adjustment);

  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (self), panel);
}
```

I have no clue what the problem here could be if this is indeed the problem and do not know how to proceed. I wonder what resource it is looking for and why it is not there. Where could I find this and how can I fix this problem?

I've actually obtained a backtrace

```
    Thread 1 "gnome-control-c" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004c9a5d in ?? ()
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x00000000004c9a5d in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00007ffff0b74f75 in g_closure_invoke ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x00007ffff0b86f82 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x00007ffff0b8fbcc in g_signal_emit_valist ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x00007ffff0b8ffaf in g_signal_emit ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x00007ffff0b793a4 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x00007ffff0b7b861 in g_object_notify ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#7  0x00007ffff58587e2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libaccountsservice.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#8  0x00007ffff0e424e3 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---return
No symbol table info available.
#9  0x00007ffff0e42b96 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#10 0x00007ffff0e80a5b in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#11 0x00007ffff0e424e3 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#12 0x00007ffff0e42b96 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#13 0x00007ffff0e7568a in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#14 0x00007ffff0e424e3 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#15 0x00007ffff0e42519 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#16 0x00007ffff089b68a in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#17 0x00007ffff089ba40 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#18 0x00007ffff089baec in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#19 0x00007ffff0e5770d in g_application_run () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#20 0x000000000044cff7 in main ()
No symbol table info available.
```

Comment: Nobody has ran into a similar issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to open the user settings as root. (Really, on a fresh install.) All I had to do was type `useradd tempuser1` and then the reopen the user settings! I guess that my segfualt occurred because there were "no users" (because root doesn't count).

I'm on the latest version of Kali.

Comment: WOW! You sir are clever, hehe. Nice one!